# Make CMake update header file before building

Tags: c++, cmake, build, pre-build-event

I have a header file `version.h` containing version information. Before every build, I want CMake to ensure that the version information is up to date. As a test, I've set up CMake to touch the file before every build. That should cause all source files that include the file to be recompiled on every build. Here is how it works:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
add_library(MY_APP STATIC main.cpp version.h)

add_custom_target(UPDATE_VERSION
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h
)

add_dependencies(MY_APP UPDATE_VERSION)
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "version.h"
```

On every build, the first output I get is `/usr/local/bin/cmake -E touch version.h`, and the timestamp of the file is changed. Great! However, `main.cpp` is only compiled on every other build! It seems that whether `main.cpp` should be compiled is determined before `version.h` is updated. Probably something like this happens:

1. List `main.cpp` for compilation if `version.h` is newer than `main.obj`
2. `touch version.h`
3. Compile `main.cpp` if it was listed for compilation

Whenever `main.cpp` is compiled, `main.obj` will be newer than `version.h` in step 1 during the next build, so then `main.cpp` will not be compiled. In the next run again, `version.h` will be newer than `main.obj` in step 1, and `main.cpp` is compiled again.

At least this is my assumption to why it does not work. How can I update build `version.h` so that `main.cpp` is compiled every time?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and Ninja.

Comment: Does listing the file touched via `BYPRODUCTS` help? Btw: I strongly recommend not generating files in the source directory, since this can easily result to issues when setting up multiple build dirs with different configurations based on the same source dir. Generated files should go into the binary directories...

Comment: Yes! That helped! Feel free to write a proper answer, and I'll accept it. And thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using your current modification timestamp approach, you might want to mark the generated file as a byproduct of the custom target using the `BYPRODUCTS` argument of `add_custom_target`, which will give the source file [the `GENERATED` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/GENERATED.html#prop_sf:GENERATED). And/or add the `ALL` argument.

Using file timestamps is depending on whether the generated buildsystem lacks the sophistication to look at whether the content of a file has changed. I think you'd do better to actually change the content of the file. Ex. putting `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P /absolute/path/to/write_stamp_file.cmake`, where `write_stamp_file.cmake` contains something like this:

```
string(TIMESTAMP timestamp "%s" UTC)
file(WRITE "${training_stamp_file}" "// UTC: ${timestamp}")
```

Of course, that's assuming a buildsystem that lacks the sophistication to detect whether the changes made in a dirty header actually necessitate re-compilation of a source file that `#include`s it, but... that's another problem. There is [the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` source file property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html), but at the time of this writing, only the Makefile and Ninja generators support it.